# How to display the value retrieved using Diesel in HTML using a Tera template in Rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket, tera

I want to display a value retrieved from the database with Diesel and serve it as HTML using a Tera template with Rocket:

```
#[get("/")]
fn index(db: DB) -> Template {
    use mlib::schema::users::dsl::*;
    let query = users.first::<User>(db.conn()).expect("Error loading users");
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&query).unwrap();
    println!("query = {:?}", &serialized);
    Template::render("index", &serialized)
}
```

[The full sample code is here](https://github.com/lion-man44/sandbox-rocket/tree/6ed2db440e3543c32406cf5c6aade6930e114f6a/src)

It receives `User { id: 1, name: "yamada" }` from the database in `#[get("/")]` of `src/main.rs` and tries to render it with a template. It looks good to me, but this error is returned:

```
Error: Error rendering Tera template 'index': Failed to value_render 'index.html.tera': context isn't an object
```

Comment: Why are you deriving and the manually implementing `Serialize` for `User`? Just use the derived Serialization and it should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: I thought that I do not need that.

However, it is required at compile time.

1. Comment out `impl Serialize for User`
2. Comment out `let serialized = serde_json :: to_string (& query) .unwrap ();`
3. `$ cargo run`

`Template::render("index", &query) // error the trait 'serde::ser::Serialize' is not implemented for 'mlib::models::User'`

Comment: @belst Please let me teach if you do not mind.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your English is fine, but the code is not up to the standards expected here. Please review how to create a [MCVE]. Ideally, you would to provide a single code block, *inside this question*, that an answerer could copy and paste locally to generate the same error. I can almost guarantee that you can remove some large part of your question (maybe Diesel?) and replace it with hard-coded values to eliminate it as a possible source of the error.

Comment: Thank you for editing.
I would like to ask questions from the next carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you everything you need to know:

```
context isn't an object
```

And what is `context`? Check out the docs for `Template::render`:

```
fn render<S, T>(name: S, context: &T) -> Template 
    where S: AsRef<str>,
          T: Serialize,
```

This [MCVE](/help/mcve) shows the problem:

**src/main.rs**

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

extern crate rocket;
extern crate rocket_contrib;

use rocket_contrib::Template;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Template {
    let serialized = "hello".to_string();
    Template::render("index", &serialized)
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.1.6"
rocket_codegen = "0.1.6"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.1.6"
features = ['tera_templates']
```

**templates/index.html.tera**

```
<html />
```

Most templating engines work against a data structure that maps a name to a value. In many cases, this is something as simple as a `HashMap`, but Rocket allows you to pass in anything that can be serialized. This is *intended* to allow passing in a struct, but it also allows you to pass in things that *do not map names to values*, like a pure string.

You have two choices:

1. Create a `HashMap` (or maybe a `BTreeMap`) of values.
2. Implement `Serialize` for a struct and pass that in.

Here's the first option:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut serialized = HashMap::new();
serialized.insert("greeting", "hello");
Template::render("index", &serialized)
```

Comment: Apparently I seemed to be terribly confused.

As you said, i could implement it with HashMap.
However, it was lost sight of all the time due to other errors.
Thanks.